# Add svg file into option tag

Tags: html, svg

I have an option tag like this

```
<option value="change" data-unit="{{ currency_string }}">{{ currency_string|upper }}<option>
```

However I want to add my currency string as a specific symbol of it so I want to integrate svg file inside it. Normally I am using `fontello.css` so I was using

```
<span class="iconname">
```

directly but for option tag I could not.

Can someone tell me how can I integrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me i can add the "font-ello" fonts just fine.
Note that the cdn and urls i use will differ a lot from browser to browser.
This is just a test, works in firefox.
There is probably a issue with the how you included the font.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  src: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/entypo-fontello/0.1/entypo.eot');
  src: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/entypo-fontello/0.1/entypo.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/entypo-fontello/0.1/entypo.woff') format('woff'), url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/entypo-fontello/0.1/entypo.ttf') format('truetype'), url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/entypo-fontello/0.1/entypo.svg#entypo') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.entypo {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>span elements</span>
<p>without font-ello</p>
<span class=""></span>
<p>with font-ello</p>
<br>
<br/>
<span class="entypo"></span>
<p>option fontello</p>
<select>
  <option class="entypo"></option>
  <option class="entypo"></option>
</select>
<p>nofontello</p>
<select>
  <option class=""></option>
  <option class=""></option>
</select>
```